# How to get the account balance on the sepolia network using Metamask SDK in Unity?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, metamask, json-rpc

I have installed the metamask SDK for Unity and I am playing around with the MetaMask Main scene. I tried to add a button to get the wallet balance:

```cs
        public async void AskBalance()
        {
            string msgParams = "latest";
            string from = MetaMaskUnity.Instance.Wallet.SelectedAddress;

            var paramsArray = new string[] { from, msgParams };

            var request = new MetaMaskEthereumRequest
            {
                Method = "eth_getBalance",
                Parameters = paramsArray
            };
            onTransactionSent?.Invoke(this, EventArgs.Empty);
            await MetaMaskUnity.Instance.Wallet.Request(request);
        }
```

but I run into a json formatting error:

```
On Failure: System.Exception: {"code":-32603,"message":"Internal JSON-RPC error.","data":{"code":-32600,"message":"invalid request"}}
```

I don't know what I am doing wrong as the debug logs seem to show that the message is correct from what I can tell from the [API documentation](https://ethereum.org/en/developers/docs/apis/json-rpc/#eth_getbalance):

```
MetaMask: {"id":"InternalMetamaskId","method":"eth_getBalance","params":["0xmypublicwalletaddress","latest"]}
```

What am I missing?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The MetaMaskEthereumRequest object is likely missing the JSON-RPC field which is required. Please update your code and let me know if this solves your problem.